# Play card before previous player has finished its turn

Tags: uno

Is it a legal play when:

- player 1 , plays a green draw 2 card
- player 3, plays a green 4 card before player 2 can play their yellow draw 2 card

Comment: Per the rule book, your question doesn't make sense.  Are you playing with a house rule that allows you to play another draw 2 instead of having to draw 2?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the rules](https://www.unorules.com/):

> **Draw Two** – When a person places this card, the next player will have
>   to pick up two cards and forfeit his/her turn. It can only be played
>   on a card that matches by color, or on another Draw Two. If turned up
>   at the beginning of play, the first player draws two cards and gets
>   skipped.

You can not play a second draw-2. Although this seems to be a common house rule.

Then again, it is nice to wait until the player has drawn the two cards before playing the next card.

Comment: Actually you need to wait for the player to draw two cards before you can take your turn since it is possible that the player may need to draw all prior draw actions need to be completed.